# RecyclerView.ViewHolder's setIsRecyclable() func

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-widget, android-viewholder

I want to set my view holder to not recycle, here's the code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
}
```

However, when I see the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#setIsRecyclable(boolean), it is written that the setIsRecycleable() should always be paired and I have no idea about this. Can anybody provide a sample code for this case? When should I call the setIsRecyclable(true) again? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not recycling the `ViewHolder` just means that specific `ViewHolder` will be retained and not overwritten when there is new data to bind, the problem with that is the `Adapter` will then need to supply another `ViewHolder` to make up for the one it can't reuse.

That is why you need to eventually let it recycle i.e. `setIsRecycleable(true)` because it kinda defeats the point of the `RecyclerView` if it ends up having to create new views to represent data.

A reason you might want to turn off the recycle is to avoid interruptions, maybe the `ViewHolder` is playing an animation, or loading a video. Once its done you could then turn on the recycle, to release the `ViewHolder` to make sure it can be used again.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the recycle is related to viewType.
You just change every itemType is unique
like:

```
@Override
public int getItemType(int position){
    return position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Listview in this case. The whole meaning of recyclerview is to recycle the view.
Else see this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36275862/3094367